# PlayerCount in a room [PHOTON]

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am doing a multiplayer game and I want my player to be able to join the room when there is one player available (other than him).I wanted to appear a text that said : " Waiting.." till one player will joint the room. I tried this 2 codes in OnJoinedRoom(), but should I create another function like FindOpponent() ? this are the codes :

```css
 if(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 2)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.IsOpen = false;
        }
```

but didn't work 
and neither this :

```css
  int playerCount = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount;
        if(playerCount != 2)
        {
            waitingStatusText.text = "Waiting for opponent";
        }
```

this is the script that I am using :

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class MPManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IPunObservable
{
    public PlayFabAuth auth;

    


    public string GameVersion;
    public Text connectState;
    
    public GameObject[] DisableOnConnected;
    public GameObject[] DisableOnJoinRoom;
    public GameObject[] EnableOnConnected;
    public GameObject[] EnableOnJoinRoom;
    public LoadedPlayer loadPlayer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        connectState.text = "Connection: " + PhotonNetwork.NetworkClientState;
    }
    public void ConnectToMaster()
    {
        //  PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }
    public override void OnJoinedLobby(){
        
        foreach(GameObject disable in DisableOnConnected){
            disable.SetActive(false);
        }
        foreach (GameObject enable in EnableOnConnected){
            enable.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        
    }

    public void CreateOrJoin()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveLobby();
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }
    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {

        RoomOptions rm = new RoomOptions
        {
            
            MaxPlayers = 3,
            IsVisible = true

        };
        int rndID = Random.Range(0, 3000);
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Default: " + rndID, rm, TypedLobby.Default);
    }
   
    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    { 
        foreach (GameObject disable in DisableOnJoinRoom)
        {
            disable.SetActive(false);
        }
        foreach (GameObject enable in EnableOnJoinRoom)
        {
            enable.SetActive(true);

        }
        Debug.Log(loadPlayer.currentPlayer.name);

        GameObject player =  PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(loadPlayer.currentPlayer.name , Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, 0);
        

    }
    public override void OnLeftRoom()
   
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
       
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because you are having the players to join random rooms at the beginning so that each player ends up in a different, random room. This way you would have many rooms with one player in it.

Comment: it's not about joining in random rooms , I want to player to not be able to join any room before is still existing one player online wanting to join too

Comment: You may want to use GetRoomList function when you join the lobby: https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v1/class_photon_network.html#aeef2085375accb7d4bc88e60cbe15eb9 It will return a list with RoomInfo of the rooms in it. You can traverse them to find out which rooms have 1 player only and have the client join that room, not a random room. The GetRoomList would trigger the OnRoomListUpdated callback so you will need to implement that to read the updated room list: https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/12725/getting-room-list-in-pun-2\

Comment: [In my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61462854/1449056), I mentioned `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` callback. Implement that to know when the second/other remote players join the room.